# Determining total number of HABTM associations through class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two associated models:

```
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :investigators, class_name: "Person"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :technicians, class_name: "Person"
end
```

and

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :facilities
end
```

If I instantiate both investigators and technicians I can get the number of each associated with a particular facility using e.g.

```
numtechs = myfacility.technicians.size
numinvests = myfacility.investigators.size
```

etc. But how do I return the total number of people associated with a facility. Trying

```
numpeople = myfacility.people.size
```

doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to do this in one swoop?

Thanks.

Comment: Wait! I've just re-read my initial post - The second model should have said 'has_and_belongs_to_many :facilities'. I'll edit it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no single association between `Facility` and `People` that you can enumerate/count. You have set up two separate associations, albeit accessible only from one side. You have not provided any way to reference the associations from `People` as there are no corresponding HABTM references to `Facility` in `People`.

You can sum the size the two associations you've shown, or if you are concerned about overlap/duplication in the associations, enumerate/count the unique `User` references.

Comment: Hi Peter. Okay, that's a shame. I'm not particularly concerned about overlap. I'm intending to extend the facility model to many different types of person in addition to the two defined above and will have several scenarios whereby I want to check if any 'people' exist associated with that facility (hence hoping there was a way to do that using the fact that I've referred to the actual people model through the class_name in each). I could just write a quick helper function I suppose. Thanks for your help